# LiveData no longer works when moved into interface

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an interface that works with a state.

```
interface HasState<S> {
    val state: S?
}
```

and in implementation the state is exposed via liveData. Everything works fine like this:

```
class StateThing: HasState<State> {
    override val state = State()

    val liveData = MutableLiveData<State>()

    // functions which update liveData
}
```

Except the moment I move the livedata into the `HasState` interface and override it in the implementation, it breaks. This does not work:

```
interface HasState<S> {
    val state: S?
    val liveData: MutableLiveData<S>
}

class StateThing: HasState<State> {
    override val state = State()

    override val liveData = MutableLiveData<State>()

    // functions which update liveData
}
```

The HasState still exposes the liveData as before, but now the `liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner)` function never receives an Observer event.

Why is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Where is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? *Why is there a difference between the two?* Without MCVE we can assume that you never call `liveData.set/postValue`

Comment: *The HasState still exposes the liveData as before.* In the first example the HasState actually would not expose the liveData, only the state directly.